# Does using the Openstack client glance image-create command require that it be repeated to all controllers in the environment?

Tags: openstack

Working on creating an OpenStack environment under Fuel for 18 XenServer based physical servers based on some prior development work which started with 4 physical servers. In the original configuration, there was only one OpenStack controller. Due to the XenServer hypervisor requirement, the images have to be custom massaged. This induced the developers to use the OpenStack CLI client and the glance image-create command for image installation, vs. using the Fuel Horizon dashboard GUI.
I'm adding at least two other controllers as recommended by best practices.

The question is pretty generic, I hope.

When using the OpenStack client CLI glance command, you set up the environment for communication purposes. Does the glance command in this configuration create the image on ALL controllers or just one?

When I look at the available images via the Fuel Horizon dashboard, the newly created image IS available. My concern is whether it is on all of the controllers? And if not, is there a way to level set all of the controllers WRT images?

Thank you for your time,

Ed Kiefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two controllers (and one Openstack region) configured properly. You should only ever need to upload the image once. If it is only available from one controller, something with your setup is wrong.